# How to get city name without internet

Tags: android, gps, google-geocoder

I have a gps class which returns lat,long. And i'm trying to get the city name or address from this coordinates with geocoder.
It works well with internet but without internet it says: connection timeout.

is it possible to get city name or anything without internet?

Comment: fetch the city name for lat long first time using internet. Store it locally and then nxt time use that, instead of fetching from internet.

Comment: Save all cities with corosponding lat,long in an offline database in your phone (This is maybe to big for your application/sd-card)an implement the lookup yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create a city database on your app and check lat & lng to determine the city.

You can download database from internet : http://www.sqldumpster.com/databases/geographic/

Comment: I'm sure you can find hungary sql database on Google ;) Look at that : http://www.geopostcodes.com/Hungary

Comment: Full the database from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_Hungary ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a list of the biggest 20.000 or 40.000 cities of the world from 
[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org).

You read that file in at startup. Probably you will ne a geospatial index like a quad tree for fast search. You may first start using a brute force search.